# Android Client and C server file transfer

Tags: android, c, sockets, client-server

I am trying to transfer some files from my android application to a server. The server side coding is in `C language`. I have implemented a service in my application which takes the file path and ends the file via `OutputStream`. But I am not able to implement the server side code to accept the incoming file. Here is my code:

**Client Side (Android App)**

```
public class Servic extends Service
{
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private static final  String SERVER_IP = "192.168.43.112";
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
    private Socket socket;
    Thread ClientThread = null;
    String st = null;
    String path = null;

public void onCreate() 
{

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    path=(String) intent.getExtras().get("path"); 

    isRunning = true;
    this.ClientThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
    this.ClientThread.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    isRunning = false;
}

public class ClientThread implements Runnable 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr,SERVERPORT);

            File file = new File(path);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            out.write((int)file.length());
            int count,file_size;

            while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                System.out.println(count);
                out.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            fis.close();
            bis.close();
        } 
    } 
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}
}
```

**Server Side (C language)**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
WSADATA wsa;
socklen_t addrlen;
SOCKET s , new_socket;
char buffer[256];
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
int c,n;
int result;

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("ERROR initlizaing winsock2 dll : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    return 1; // exit program with error.
}

printf("Initialised.\n");

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(s == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("error at creating socket :%d" ,WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("socket created\n");

memset(&server, 0, sizeof server);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons(6000);

if (bind(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Bind fialed with errror code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

listen(s , 3);

printf("waiting for incoming connections\n");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
new_socket = accept(s , (struct sockaddr *)&client,&c);
if(new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("accept fialed with error code : %d" ,WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Connection acceptëd");

//as per my knowledge, file accepting code should be somewhere here.

getchar();
closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
}
```

It would be helpful if you can help me with something over here.

Comment: `file accepting code should be somewhere here.`. Indeed. What is the problem exactly? What did you try?

Comment: Yes, you now need to read from the socket `iret=recv(new_socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0);` and write to a file `write(fd, buffer, iret);`. The opposite of the client part. Repeat until iret <= 0

Answer (score 1):

Check whether this works.This code is written to send a file to a client
server: https://github.com/dinanjana/CO323/blob/master/SocketProgrammingWithC/Lab03/TCPServer.c
client:
https://github.com/dinanjana/CO323/blob/master/SocketProgrammingWithC/Lab03/TCPClient.c
As @ja_mesa mentioned you need to call recv function inn order to get the message